# How to setup a local password on Windows Creators Update?

Tags: windows

Since my Microsoft password is too long, I have been using a local password on my computer to sign in. Not the pin, just a text pass. Now I've reset the PC after Creators Update and I don't see an option for setting up a local password, just the PIN.

Is the local password gone? If not, how to set it now? I don't see it on the Sign-in Settings..

Comment: What makes you think the password length exceeded the accepted Windows user password length? My 32 character Microsoft Account password is accepted when I logged into my account on all my PCs.

Comment: No the local password is not gone. You may be able to change it by pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL, then choose Change Password. Leave the current password row blank and type in the new password twice. Can't test this as I'm joined to a domain, so it works differently. Therefor not an answer but a comment. If it works I'll happily write you an answer though.